# Format List into String (String Format Compatible w/ ArcPy's Select by Attribute Function)

Tags: python, arcpy

I need to format a list into a string so that I can pass the string into ArcPy's Select by Attribute function.

My list is as follows -

```
values = [30477, 35136, 4327]
```

I would like to format the list into a string and store the formatted string in a variable. The required string format for ArcPy's Select by Attribute function looks like this -

```
values_string = "OBJECTID = 30477 Or OBJECTID = 35136 Or OBJECTID = 4327"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values_string = f"OBJECTID = {values[0]} Or OBJECTID = {values[1]} Or OBJECTID = {values[2]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**This could be a nice example use of f-strings in python. (works for python 3.6+)**

```
def string_cleaner(values_list):
    single_string = ''
    for value in values_list:
        single_string += 'OBJECTID = {} Or '.format(value)
    return single_string[:-4]
```

**You can pass multiple variable arguments**

```
single_string += '{} = {} Or '.format('OBJECTID' ,value)
```

**To make it even more readable you can pass variable names within the curly brackets**

```
single_string += 'OBJECTID = {obj_id} Or '.format(obj_id=value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I modified the return statement as `return single_string[:-4]`, so that the string ends with a value instead of `' Or '`.

Comment: Ah, good catch. i'll edit the post to reflect your suggestion.